# JestJS: How to get different promise results of a mocked function and test for thrown error?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to test a function (`example()`), which uses another one (`validateDataset`). As I only want to test the `example()` function I mock the `validateDataset()`.

Of course each test needs a different result of the mocked function. But how do I set different promise results for the mocked function? In my attempt shown below the mocked function always return the same value.

So in this example I cannot test for the thrown error.

**functions.js**

```
import { validateDataset } from './helper/validation'

export async function example (id) {
  const { docElement } = await validateDataset(id)
  if (!docElement) throw Error('Missing content')
  return docElement
}
```

**functions.test.js**

```
import { example } from './functions'

jest.mock('./helper/validation', () => ({
  validateDataset: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
    docMain: {},
    docElement: {
      data: 'result'
    }
  }))
}))

describe('example()', () => {
  test('should return object', async () => {
    const result = await example('123')
    expect(result.data).toBe('result')
  })
  test('should throw error', async () => {
    const result = await example('123')
    // How to get different result (`null`) in this test
    // How to test for the thrown error?
  })
})
```

Comment: Yes, You need to import toast in your test file. Alternatively, you can also check whether your `t` function is being called with `error:no-admin-console` or not.

Comment: @HardikModha Sorry, I've edited the wrong post and started a bounty on that. Your comment is now out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's great about Jest mocking, is that you can mock-out the whole module, and by requiring its default or named exports, you still get a mock, which you can implement and reimplement however and wherever you like.

I've posted a sample implementation of the test that expects `validateDataset` call to fail. I also left some comments for brevity.

```
import { example } from './example';
import { validateDataset } from './helper/validation';

// Declare export of './helper/validation' as a Mock Function.
// It marks all named exports inside as Mock Functions too.
jest.mock('./helper/validation');

test('example() should return object', async () => {
  // Because `validateDataset` is already mocked, we can provide
  // an implementation. For this test we'd like it to be original one.
  validateDataset.mockImplementation(() => {
    // `jest.requireActual` calls unmocked module
    return jest.requireActual('./helper/validation').validateDataset();
  });
  const result = await example('123');
  expect(result.data).toBe('result');
});

test('example() should throw error', async () => {
  // Worth to make sure our async assertions are actually made
  expect.assertions(1);
  // We can adjust the implementation of `validateDataset` however we like,
  // because it's a Mock Function. So we return a null `docElement`
  validateDataset.mockImplementation(() => ({ docElement: null }));
  try {
    await example('123');
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error.message).toEqual('Missing content');
  }
});
```

Hope that clears things out.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, the complete validation file gets mocked. Is it possible to mock only one named export? And why do you use `requireActual`? Could you explain this a bit more? I mean, I would return also a value for the mocked function as you did it in the second test. Didn't even think about using the unmocked module...

Comment: If you modify the dependency using the import, you are overriding the entire module. You could try to do module.functionName = () => {whatever} to do what you want. Another solution is to send the function you need as a dependency for the component instead of making the import inside the class. Look up 'Dependency Injection'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to change a variable within `function.js`.

functions.test.js would look like:

```
import * as rewire from 'rewire';
const functionsModule = rewire('functions.js');

describe('example()', () => {
    var functionsModule;

    test('should return object', done => {
        functionsModule.__set__('validateDataset', () => {
            Promise.resolve({
                docMain: {},
                docElement: {
                    data: 'result'
                }
            })
        });
        functionsModule.example('123').then(result => {
            expect(result.docElement.data).toBe('result');
            done(); 
        });

    })

    test('should throw error', done => {
        functionsModule.__set__('validateDataset', () => {
            return Promise.reject();
        });
        functionsModule.example('123').catch(done);
    });

})
```

Comment: How should the the initial mock of `validateDataset` looks like? In my code I did it before `describe`...

Comment: I would use rewire or jest mock in the beginning of each test like i just did. This way the code is alot clearer in my opinion. Not sure if i answered your question.